# Is it normal to have multiple users connected to one Pub Sub topic that contains user specific data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I’m new to gcloud pub sub and I want to implement it so that I can communicate from server to a client self hosted node JS server without the user having to publicly expose a web server from their network. I want to send user specific data across these real time streams but is it normal for multiple users to be subscribed to a single topic when it is only intended for single user events? Is the normal approach to have the streams contain non-sensitive user data and then the client decides whether or not to act if it’s applicable or to create a new topic per user to ensure that no users can even see data related to another user for obvious security reasons? I'm struggling to find any pub sub services where they suggests ways of handling this use case for user specific data streams

Comment: Can you clarify your design? I'm not sure to understand how the messages are consumed, what are the client/users (where is hosted the PubSub consumer) and what are publishing messages in the topic. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jack_b_321,I have posted a solution.The episode link I mentioned in my answer is a perfect example for what you're looking for. If my answer addresses your question you can consider accepting and upvoting. I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cloud Pub/Sub for point-to-point communication of this nature is considered an anti-pattern. Pub/Sub is generally designed for persistent streams of data moving between applications or for data ingestion for streaming analytics. If the subscriber client is a dynamic, per-user instance that is only meant to receive a subset of the messages, it is generally an indicator that Pub/Sub may not be the best tool.

There are several reasons why Pub/Sub doesn't fit this paradigm well:

1. There is a limit of 10,000 subscriptions per topic. Therefore, if you try to use a single topic, you can have no more than  10,000 users. You will have to be very careful around garbage collecting subscriptions for subscribers that go away in order to ensure you can even have 10,000 active users.
2. There is a limit of 10,000 topics per project. This means that using a topic per user has the same aforementioned users.
3. Whether using filtering or allowing the client to filter the messages itself, you will pay for the delivery of all messages to every subscriber.
4. You have to consider the authentication model and how users are granted permission to create a topic or subscription or how they can create a subscriber to a subscription.

Typically, it is better to put a proxy between Pub/Sub and your end users. You can use Pub/Sub to ingest messages and send them to a server that you run. Users connect directly to that server and the server forwards appropriate messages to clients and then acknowledges them when the user processes the message. As needed, you can scale this to multiple instances of the server. Depending on the scale, it may be feasible to have a subscription per server in order to allow every instances to get all messages (and immediately ack messages it doesn't need to forward on to users). Filters may not be feasible in this scenario unless you can know exactly which messages are intended for which servers.

While you are trying to prevent the exposure of a web server in this instance, it would also be a more typical approach. If each message is able to encode the host and port to which the message must go, then any arbitrary server can receive the Pub/Sub message and send it along to the appropriate client, which makes horizontal scaling a lot easier. It also avoids having to think about the permission model of who is allowed to open a connection to your server.

Answer (score 0):

An application(publisher) can create and send messages to a single or multiple topic. Subscription is a  named resource representing the stream of messages from a single, specific topic, to be delivered to the subscribing application. Applications with a subscription to a single or multiple topics will receive messages from it.

We can use multiple subscriptions for the same topic and we can also send data from multiple publishers to the same topic. For example, if you have two publishers `P_A` and `P_B` and they are sending messages to a single Topic(let's call the topic name as `T_1`) and two subscriptions(`S_A` and `S_B`) subscribed to the same topic. Then the message sent from both `P_A` and `P_B` will be forwarded to both subscriptions `S_A` and `S_B`. Both the subscriptions will receive the same messages from the publishers. When a topic has multiple subscriptions, then every message has to be sent to a subscriber receiving messages on behalf of each subscription.

If you want to filter messages you can consider the pub/sub [filter message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter#:%7E:text=The%20Pub%2FSub%20service%20automatically,can%20have%20a%20different%20filter.) feature.

When you receive messages from a subscription with a filter, you only receive the messages that match the filter. The Pub/Sub service automatically acknowledges the messages that don't match the filter. You can filter messages by their attributes, but not by the data in the message.

You can refer to these [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjEam95VLiI),[link2](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas) and [episode](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIivdWyY5sqKwVLe4BLJ-vlh9r9zCdOse) for more information.